# Creating another user for a certain domain

Tags: linux, bash

I typically tend to log in as root, which I know is bad practice.

So I created another user, let's call it `user1`.  Except now when I log in as that user I am placed in an empty /home directory and it is pretty useless.

The problem is I want `user1` to have access to another users /home/ directory, effectively cloning the other users permissions.  How can I do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with commands like `cp`, `chmod`, and  `chown`?

Comment: @John1024 yes I am, but last time I used them I ruined everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by having the same user id (UID) for both users, but it is a really bad practice and may have unintended consequences. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/427107/533244) for a comprehensive discussion about it.

A better way is either having those users in the same group and setting R or RW group permissions on their homes, or better still using extended attributes (man `setfattr`), or allowing your user to `sudo su - <anotheruser>` via `/etc/sudoers` file, or allowing your user to sudo to root.

#### Same group option

First create a special group, say team_a:

```
groupadd team_a
```

Then set that group to your users (say `user1` and `user2`). By default each user is created in a new group with the same name as the user. You'll set team_a as the main group, and leave the individual groups as secondary groups:

```
for user in user1 user2; do usermod -g team_a $user; usermod -a -G $user $user; done
```

Then update permissions on user2's home, giving full access to any members of the `team_a` group, to the folder and any files and folders contained in it, recursively; this would allow any member of `team_a` accessing `user2`'s home folder and files, but you're not granting access on any other users (e.g. the following doesn't provide access to members of `team_a` to your `user1`'s home folder):

```
chmod -R g+rwX ~user2
```

Note that `user2` could remove those permissions at any time, or create new files without granting access permissions to the group.

Finally, ensure that your other user(s) will create any files with full access for members of that group:

```
echo "umask 002" >> ~user2/.profile
```

#### Your user belonging to other users' default group:

Perhaps simpler than the above, you can add your `user1` user to the default groups of any other users. By default in most Linux distros and UNIX systems, the default group permissions on new files is full access to the group when the user's group name is the same as the user's name, so there's no need to manipulate `umask` for those users in this case.

Setting `user1` to belong also in `user2`'s default group:

```
usermod -a -G user2 user1
```

Granting access access to members of `user2` group to `user2`'s home folder:

```
chmod g+rwX ~user2
```

Comment: Could you explain further the group permissions idea, with CLI examples please? :D

Comment: @Chud37 Added examples

Comment: @Chud37 Added another perhaps simpler option, plus a necessary extra requirement (umask) on the previous example

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister - You might want to change the first usermod command, so the new group is appended, to the user.  You get rid of one line code by doing that.